# Data import into MemGraph Lab Beta version

Tags: memgraphdb

I have been trying to import data into MemGraph Lab Beta version using the datasets and code provided here :
https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/v0.14.1/how_to_guides/import-data/
I have used the CSVs provided as follows

Store the following in comment_nodes.csv.

id:ID(COMMENT_ID),country:string,browser:string,content:string,:LABEL

0,Croatia,Chrome,yes,Message;Comment

1,United Kingdom,Chrome,thanks,Message;Comment

2,Germany,,LOL,Message;Comment

3,France,Firefox,I see,Message;Comment

4,Italy,Internet Explorer,fine,Message;Comment

Now, let's add forum_nodes.csv.

id:ID(FORUM_ID),title:string,:LABEL

0,General,Forum

1,Support,Forum

2,Music,Forum

3,Film,Forum

4,Programming,Forum

And finally, set relationships between comments and forums in relationships.csv.

:START_ID(COMMENT_ID),:END_ID(FORUM_ID),:TYPE

0,0,POSTED_ON

1,1,POSTED_ON

2,2,POSTED_ON

3,3,POSTED_ON

4,4,POSTED_ON

I then loaded them in as follows :
mg_import_csv --overwrite --nodes=(file path)comment_nodes.csv --nodes=(file path)forum_nodes.csv --relationships=(file path)relationships.csv

and the console gave the following output message:
Created '/var/lib/memgraph/durability/snapshots/....' in 0.01 seconds

Now I know my data is stored here: var/lib/memgraph/durability/snapshots...
but I get access denied when I go into that folder and when I go into Memgraph lab and query MATCH n RETURN n I do net get my nodes returned from the data that I loaded so the Lab is definitely not picking up the file from the location it is stored in.

I would assume I am missing some setting that would allow me to make sure the newly loaded file is getting picked up by the MemGraph lab?
Your advice would be greatly appreciated,
thanks,
Kat

Comment: How did you install Memgraph (deb, rpm or docker)?

Comment: Probably the snapshot created by running mg_import_csv hasn't been loaded. Could you please also post Memgraph console logs here?